# What is the strange taste feeling that one gets when eating a quince or unripe plum or persimmon?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a particular taste that I could never quite translate in English. It is not bitter, although it sometimes occurs with it. The best example is eating a raw quince fruit. The mouth and tongue get a sort of dry feeling. Similar taste can be experienced with some persimmon fruit, and unripe plums. I know the word in French (*âpre*) and Bulgarian (*стипцив*). Google translates these as *rough*, but that somehow seems unlikely. Any ideas?

Comment: [Astringent](http://www.eattasteheal.com/ETH_6tastes.htm)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

***Astringent***, maybe?

Astringent taste is the least common of all the 6 Tastes and can be found in legumes (such as beans and lentils), fruits (including cranberries, pomegranates, pears, and dried fruit), vegetables (such as, broccoli, cauliflower, artichoke, asparagus and turnip), grains (such as rye, buckwheat, and quinoa), spices and herbs (including turmeric and marjoram), coffee, and tea.

http://www.eattasteheal.com/ETH_6tastes.htm

Comment: Haha - same link as my simultaneous comment! I always cite the stringy threads down the sides of a peeled banana as a typical example if I'm talking to someone who doesn't understand what I'm talking about. "Raw" olives are another (extreme) example, but not many Brits have actually tried biting into one of those.

Comment: Imagining persimmon (Sharon fruit) juice is pretty vivid for me.

Comment: It's a good one isn't it @AleksandarSavkov.  It's a photo of a poster from a Basque magazine (Argia).

Comment: Exactly. Aronia is famous for that taste, and apparently dubbed _chokeberry_ for that very reason (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronia).

Comment: For the record, I'll note acerbity, which the Shorter Oxford English Dictionary defines as "Sourness of taste, with astringency"; and acerbic "Sour or harsh" (same source).
I also disagree this question already has an answer at the link put in the header ("what is the numb sensation ...) - the question here seems to be more about a taste that 'puts one's teeth on edge' rather than 'numbness', which anyone drinking kava will know is quite different.

Answer (score 4):

"Astringent" is excellent. But, if you are looking for a more common term. Consider **harsh**.

Example:
[image]

[(source)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=vQJUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=harsh%20persimon&source=bl&ots=xNI5-LpjIs&sig=BWvH1ulspmyt4df74xUcqhzqbw4&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW8ozh95fKAhVLVRQKHQudCq8Q6AEIVDAG#v=onepage&q=harsh%20persimon&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

Unripe persimmon is extremely  **mouth-puckering**.

Answer (score 0):

"Mapakla" is the word.  This word is used in the Philippines to describe the sensation you get in your mouth after biting raw banana.

Comment: "Mapakla" is not an **English** word. It's Tagalog.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be describing the sense one also often gets from grape juice, which is a dry sensation throughout the mouth, even though it's full of liquid.  That flavor and taste is called "sec."  *Sec* is another way to say medium dry, un-sweet and is borrowed into gastronomy from wine world.

Comment: "Astringent" applies to wine too, even if there's also a French wine-specific term for it. I'm also unsure if "sec" really means astringency specifically; I think it's a more general term as you say - it also implies something about sweetness. It's just "dry" in French.

Comment: When one  puts "astringent" on their face, it's a drying alcohol.  However, when "astringent" relates to taste, it isn't used to describe something dry, but describe it as bitter, harsh, and caustic.  The OP said specifically, "It's not bitter."  Sec doesn't mean "astringent."

Comment: The astringent substance in grapes and persimmons is known as "tannins" - a term derived from that, generally used in wine to describe an astringent mouthfeel, is "tannic". "Dryness" in wine is not the same as astringency - when wine is "dry" or "sec", this means that it is not particularly sweet. As such, this answer is close to correct, but you've got your wine terms mixed up.

Comment: I think you're confusing the idea you get from "astringent" as a drying alcohol based product in cosmetics as meaning a drying flavor in wine, but it doesn't.  The word "astringent" means "drawing together."  In flavor, "astringent" describes a very bitter taste that is so harsh it makes people's faces recoil or draw together, thus "astringent."  "Sec," Latin for dry, describes that dry taste one gets in wine and grape juice, that flavor that the OP is describing.  It doesn't lean at all toward bitter.  If it leaned toward anything, it would lean towards sour, although not tangy.

Comment: astringent (adjective) - an astringent taste is one that is strong and bitter (http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/british/words-used-to-describe-specific-tastes-and-flavours)

Comment: Astringent is biting, harsh, sharp, cutting, acerbic, severe, rough, acrid, mordant, caustic flavor. It is not mild, soft, gentle. (http://www.kyrene.org/cms/lib2/AZ01001083/Centricity/Domain/1671/Food%20words.pdf)

Comment: @BenjaminHarman The first definition (strong and bitter) seems like an imprecise description (lots of people use bitter to mean really anything unpleasant), and the second seems like an attempt at a more precise description. What I know for sure is that in a culinary sense, astringent is used to refer to the specific thing that the OP is asking about. It's also present in wine, and generally more noticeable in dry wine, but "dry" isn't generally used to describe the food, especially outside of wine, while "astringent" very commonly is.

Comment: You can find plenty of examples searching on http://cooking.stackexchange.com/ (or on Google) but to try to provide a more official source: On Food and Cooking uses "astringency" to describe this: "Astringency is neither a taste nor an aroma, but a tactile sensation: that dry, puckery, rough feeling that follows a sip of strong tea or red wine, or a bite into an unripe banana or peach." Per the index, it also separately mentions astringency in the sections about chocolate, coffee, persimmons, tea, and wine. So no, it's not about being bitter - that's just a misapplication of bitter.

Comment: @Jefromi : The first source I gave was a dictionary and offered in order to establish that this wasn't just some foody's opinion.  The second source I linked directly from a food website in order to show that the dictionary definition wasn't in some way discrepant with food jargon or its use in relation to food.  Your opinion of this source material is irrelevant and unsubstantiated.  I've given evidence, two sources, whereas you've given none.  I don't need more sources.  You need sources to back up what your saying, to back up your contradictions.  Saying, "I know for sure," means nothing.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I know that you linked to sources, and my point is that those sources do not appear to match actual culinary usage. I cited one very good source already: On Food and Cooking (widely regarded as pretty much The book about science in cooking). The rest of what I said is not merely my opinion, but rather the usage I've seen widely used [on cooking.stackexchange](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=astringent) as well as in cookbooks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33984/discussion-between-jefromi-and-benjamin-harman).